# Create primary key with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I've checked documentation, multiple questions here on SO and nothing work but it should. Below my class

```
public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public int PlayerId;

    public void SetId(int id)
    {
        this.PlayerId = id;
    }

    public int GetId()
    {
        return this.PlayerId;
    }

    protected String name;

    public void SetName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String GetName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using the name convention, I even added the `[Key]` but still when I'm doing migration I receive

> Player: : EntityType 'Player' has no key defined. Define the key for
>   this EntityType. Players: EntityType: EntitySet 'Players' is based on
>   type 'Player' that has no keys defined.

What is going one ? Why this is not working ?

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `auto properties`

```
public int PlayerId { get; set; }
```

your **get/set** methods look like `Java`, in C# we usually use inline `get/set`

---

**UPDATE**:
if you want to use protected properties, you can use the code below

```
// protected property
protected int PlayerId { get; set; }
// protected get
public int PlayerId { protected get; set; }
// protected get
public int PlayerId { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: ok but what if I want to use protected fields ? Yeah I'm a java typ of guy ;) and convention where I set every field as public is for me a bit strange

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen a declaration like this. Looks like java to me :) Try to declare PlayerId as a property, not as a public field.

```
public int PlayerId { get; set; }
```

You dont need methods like GetId and SetId.

If you want to use properties having access specifier as protected or private then you need to tell that in your configuration class:

```
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }

    protected string Name { get; set; }

    public class PlayerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Player>
    {
        public PlayerConfiguration()
        {
            Property(b => b.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok but what if I want to use protected fields ? Yeah I'm a java typ of guy ;) and convention where I set every field as public is for me a bit strange

Comment: @Fixus It's not a field, it's a property.